# how to use apply function to take no names column mean?

Tags: r, apply

I practiced the ?apply example in R documentation.

```
x<-cbind(x1=3,x2=c(4:1, 2:5))
dimnames(x)[[1]]<-letters[1:8]
apply(x,2,mean,trim = .2)
```

It is the outcome.

```
x1 x2 
 3  3
```

If i just want to take the x2's mean, like

```
x2
 3
```

so i try

```
apply(x,x[,2],mean)
```

and it is error:Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

so how could i do or improvement? thanks.

Comment: Why would you use `apply` there?

Comment: First i used aggregate function and the names of x1 x2 is NULL. (list(x$x1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to use `apply` there. You can just do something like:

```
mean(x[, "x2"], trim = .2)
# [1] 3
```

If you really wanted to use `apply`, you can try something like:

```
apply(x[, "x2", drop = FALSE], 2, mean, trim = .2)
# x2 
#  3 

## apply(x[, 2, drop = FALSE], 2, mean, trim = .2)
```

In other words, select the columns you're interested in as your dataset, and then apply whatever function you want. Notice the use of `drop = FALSE` to prevent the single column from becoming a basic vector.